# Mine is maven quickstart project, i have created two classes Employee & Address

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc

This is my Employee class

```
package com.niit;
```

public class Employee {

```
private int employeeId;
private String name;
```

Now How to add `currentAddress` and `permanentAddress` in Address class?

```
Address address;


public Address getAddress() {
    return address;
}
public void setAddress(Address address) {
    this.address = address;
}
public int getEmployeeId() {
    return employeeId;
}
public void setEmployeeId(int employeeId) {
    this.employeeId = employeeId;
}
public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
```

}

This is my Address class

```
package com.niit;

public class Address {

private String Address;
private String City;
public String getAddress() {
    return Address;
}
public void setAddress(String address) {
    Address = address;
}
public String getCity() {
    return City;
}
public void setCity(String city) {
    City = city;
}

}
```

This is my Spring.xml file

```
<bean id="Employee" class="com.niit.Employee">
    <property name="Address" ref="Address"></property>
    <property name="employeeId" value="101"></property>
    <property name="name" value="abc"></property>
</bean>


<bean id="Address" class="com.niit.Address">
    <property name="Address" value="whitefield"></property>
    <property name="City" value="Banglore"></property>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use @Embeddded and @AttributeOverrides annotations to do this in your Employee entity.

```
    @Column(name=”ADDRESS”)
    @Embedded
    @AttributeOverrides({
    @AttributeOverride(name=”street”, column=@Column(name=”CURRENT_STREET_NAME”)),
    @AttributeOverride(name=”city”, column=@Column(name=”CURRENT_CITY_NAME”)),
    @AttributeOverride(name=”state”, column=@Column(name=”CURRENT_STATE_NAME”)),
    @AttributeOverride(name=”pincode”, column=@Column(name=”CURRENT_PIN_CODE”))})
    private Address currentAddress;

    @Embedded
    private Address permanentAddress;
```

The similar xml configuration for this will be something like below :

```
<attributes>
    <id name="id">
        <column name="fld_id"/>
        <generated-value generator="generator" strategy="SEQUENCE"/>
        <temporal>DATE</temporal>
        <sequence-generator name="generator" sequence-name="seq"/>
    </id>
    <version name="version"/>
    <embedded name="embeddedObject">
        <attribute-override name"subproperty">
            <column name="my_column"/>
        </attribute-override>
    </embedded>
    <basic name="status" optional="false">
        <enumerated>STRING</enumerated>
    </basic>
    <basic name="serial" optional="true">
        <column name="serialbytes"/>
        <lob/>
    </basic>
    <basic name="terminusTime" fetch="LAZY">
        <temporal>TIMESTAMP</temporal>
    </basic>
</attributes>
```

NOTE : Please modify this code based on your need as this is just for sample.